# Best place to start with Star Trek

Tags: star-trek, suggested-order

I learned quite a bit from the question [Where should I start with Star Trek? (TV series only, not the movies)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4323/where-should-i-start-with-star-trek)

I watched the first 3 episodes of TOS on netflix but just couldn't get into it.  Does TOS get better or is it likely that I wouldn't enjoy the rest of the series?

I enjoyed the 2009 movie quite a bit though.  I've been thinking about giving TNG a try.  However I don't have too much time to devote to these things.  I've also heard good things about The Wrath of Khan though as well.

My main questions:

- Would I be confused or be missing quite a bit if I watched The Wrath of Khan first?
- Does it even make sense to start with The Wrath of Khan given that I didn't enjoy the first few episodes of TOS?
- Would I be lost if I started watching TNG after that?

Comment: If you skipped TOS entirely, you won't be confused with TNG except for the names they reference and a few episodes here and there that have the TOS cast as special guests.

Comment: @Dason What is it you're looking for that isn't covered by the answers to the other, linked question?  Those answers tend to suggest new people start with the modern Treks over TOS.

Comment: @MarkTrapp It's related - I even put the link my question but that didn't answer my specific questions.  I'm alright with watching the movies first (I even ask about The Wrath of Khan) and I describe my situation a little more in depth.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [What is the recommended viewing order for first-timers to watch Star Trek TV episodes and movies?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6719/366). I fail to see how either question doesn't fully answer this one. Offer [a bounty](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) if you need more detail.

Comment: @MarkTrapp I saw that one too but I'm not an 8 year old girl and I have a little more background.  If you guys think it's not worth answering that's fine but I was just hoping to get some suggestions based on the info I provided.  Mainly how I felt about the TOS and the newer movie along with the fact that I'm alright with watching some of the movies too.

Comment: I reread the FAQ and 'Reading or viewing recommendations: I liked X, what should I watch next?' are off-topic.  I didn't recall that and remembered the other referenced threads similar to mine and just thought I'd get some input.  Thanks goes to @JulieB for providing some input.  I vote to close.

Comment: @Dason As you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started with TOS, simply because it was references so much in popular culture that I wanted to be able to get those references. It was also interesting to see Roddenberry's ideas first put to screen.

I do think the TOS gets better with some very good episodes, while limited by the budget and technology it is easy to focus on the story.

It seems to me that all subsequent series tend to have more in common with crossovers, characters and storylines. TOS is not really included in this aside from a few episodes in TNG.

I would say finish with TOS if you want to be complete but if you don't think you will enjoy it, then start with TNG.

As for the Wrath of Kahn, the trek movies 2-4 are a trilogy of sorts, so I would watch all of them. You can watch Kahn by itself, although watching the relevant TOS episode where Kahn is introduced might help.

Comment: generally you're best to start where the actors are comfortable with their roles, and the show is developing in intensity and in a new direction, usually about season 4.  Wrath of Khan, First Contact and Voyage Home are all great films to introduce the concepts.